# Getting error in the Microsoft login redirection request while executing in Jmeter

Tags: authentication, redirect, jmeter

Problem description: The request is not redirecting to the correct page.

Below screenshot for your reference.
Request name: https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf

It is a POST request and has 3 parameters:
- wa
- wresult
- wctx

image.png

- The wresult parameter has a RequestSecurityTokenResponse in xmlns format.

I have done the correlation for the below parameters in the request body:
-- Created
-- Expires
-- Name Identifier
-- Reference URI
-- Digest value
-- Signature value
-- X509Certificate

Below is the RequestSecurityTokenResponse for reference:

2020-01-03T23:16:24.215Z2020-01-04T00:16:24.215Zurn:federation:MicrosoftOnlineurn:federation:MicrosoftOnlinejsSvrT4Hd0278wfJZI2naQ==urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearermakhan_s_pub_tst@achatscanadabuys.cajsSvrT4Hd0278wfJZI2naQ==falseurn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransportjsSvrT4Hd0278wfJZI2naQ==urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearerV+SCiLxuXDzcCXnY85O64ET1mrtHvmqSeHfacBHEgLA=iVbVKXz8pYltJ2mEjZm9YUEEGJs93Fp/xaOrVz8taVplOiCXUSDtWbSk7Ps0eSctk4L4KtlUuKlXHjot03wMXVrHLJPuBGefRB73tfytGMkARkJh7jx8zn2IipF0AnQkqDuBlHAU1U/hZymigZMMMCNgEb4au29uwjK6MDoR/fPUGURlmCiBLSKsJpxeTMlKezWeGF1r1Q0PPTMZS7y1NNDIrHlWQ3i8yhEIoSk3eBhutEIhXHHz+XQZdxiswzHGTbzsPwwW6j/XGkoQ0tYmVLZsVGLCo7ZU7AMPLKkINnv4NeF8XWULhkkTInb39sCre4V2o0qzhJ6JN4J8Td6xKw==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:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertionhttp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issuehttp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey

image.png

I hope, the information gives you an idea about the problem.

Hoping for your response soon.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the described behaviour, opening https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf results into [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize where there are no `wa`, `wresult` and `wctx`, but there are certain URL parameters which can be easily [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

[image]